# Parallex effect repeats image

Tags: html, css, parallax

I created a parallax effect yesterday and thought it worked great. Today I resized my browser and saw my picture I used repeated itself. no-repeat destroyed the whole thing.

So I tried a lot of things but couldnt get anything to work.
Here is an example of what happened: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GadqK.jpg

```css
.pic {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 2.28/1;
  background: url('pictures/Coldcreekranch\ Faistenau\ Slider.jpeg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="pictures/ccr_logo.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar"></nav>

  <main>
    <div class="pic" id="parallax">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="scripts/parallax_main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: try out backround-repeat: no-repeat; on your .pic class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have added a fixed aspect ratio to the image, which means the image will be higher when the window is wider.

There is a `background-size` property which may help you, for instance `background-size: cover`.

You can read more about it and how it works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: sadly that doesnt work for me. if i user background-size: cover the picture gets really small (if i delete the aspect ratio) and if i keep the aspect ratio the picture gets zoomed in really far

Comment: @Lipe That is what `background-size: cover` does, it stretches the image to fill the whole area. You could also try the `background-size: contain` option, but that will not cover the whole area of you div